# Liquibase does not commit my changes

Tags: liquibase

I'm running Liquibase from a Java application to MSSQL with the JTDS driver. When I run the updates I see them displayed but nothing actually get's committed to the Database. Any ideas? The code below runs in a Servlet.

```
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/datasource.properties"));
        String driver = props.getProperty("database.driver");
        String url = props.getProperty("database.url");
        String username = props.getProperty("database.username");
        String password = props.getProperty("database.password");
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(con));
        Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("db.xml", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
        response.getWriter().print("<PRE>");
        liquibase.update("", response.getWriter());

        con.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new ServletException(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                log.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
    response.flushBuffer();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The update() method that takes a writer will not execute changes, but rather output what would be ran.

If you call liquibase.update("") or liquibase.update(null) instead, it will execute the changes.